# Set default value after Registration, StormPath

Tags: node.js, express, registration, stormpath

I have a simple StormPath/Express app, and AFTER a user registers, I want to set the default value for `country` to "World" (customData). Later on the user can change it to any country in their profile page.

How would I use the `preRegistrationHandler` to accomplish this (if that is the best way). Thanks.

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
    preRegistrationHandler: function (formData, req, res, next) {
    console.log('Got registration request', formData);
    next();
}

}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `postRegistrationHandler` to run code AFTER registration has completed =)

For instance:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  postRegistrationHandler: (account, req, res, next) => {
    account.getCustomData((err, data) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      data.country = 'World';
      data.save((err) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        next();
      });
    });
  });
});
```